# How to get rid of the logging startup messages in the console when using PAX logging?

Tags: logging, log4j, rcp, pax, ops4j

I have been asked to implement PAX logging on our RCP application. Basically, I have followed this  [tutorial](http://rcpquickstart.com/2009/07/10/configuring-rcp-applications-with-pax-confman/).

As you may noticed, it says that when "you run your RCP application, you should see Pax ConfMan logging output to your console". Please note: The configuration folder **can** be found, that's **not** the issue.

When I run my application, I get the following console output:

```
[Framework Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service - BundleEvent STARTED
[Start Level Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.apache.felix.fileinstall - ServiceEvent REGISTERED
[Start Level Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.apache.felix.fileinstall - ServiceEvent REGISTERED
[Framework Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.apache.felix.fileinstall - BundleEvent STARTED
[Start Level Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.eclipse.equinox.cm - ServiceEvent REGISTERED
[Start Level Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.eclipse.equinox.cm - ServiceEvent REGISTERED
[Start Level Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.apache.felix.fileinstall - ServiceEvent REGISTERED
[Framework Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.eclipse.equinox.cm - BundleEvent STARTED
[org.ops4j.pax.configmanager.internal.Activator] : Starting [org.ops4j.pax.configmanager]...
[Start Level Event Dispatcher] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.configmanager - ServiceEvent REGISTERED
[org.ops4j.pax.configmanager.internal.ConfigurationAdminFacade] : Using configuration from [configurations]
[org.ops4j.pax.configmanager.internal.ConfigurationAdminFacade] : Using configuration from [configurations]
[org.ops4j.pax.configmanager.internal.ConfigurationAdminFacade] : Register configuration [org.ops4j.pax.logging]
```

My question is: how can I get rid of this console output?

**Edit 1**
The reason for asking this question is that ideally we shouldn't be seeing anything in the console at startup unless there is a genuine problem, or we've specifically requested additional logging.

**Edit 2**
I have noticed we had an apache commons logging dependency. I assumed that it would cause some sort of conflict, so I removed it, but the output did not changed.

**Edit 3**
Issue still exists, waiting for any feedback at the moment.

Thank you in advance and apologies if I made any mistake at the question formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxlogging/Configuration

You can set the default level using the following system property:

org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level

So something like launching the app with:

```
-Dorg.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level=WARN
```

is probably what you need.